# ExecuteRestApi doubling up SalesForce.com in called address

Tags: rest-api

Afternoon everyone, I'm having an issue when using the ForceClient ExecuteRestApi method.

When using it, instead of going to this address:
https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GetDirectDebitTransactions?StartDate=01/06/2015&EndDate=30/06/2015
It instead goes to the following:
https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GetDirectDebitTransactions?StartDate=01/06/2015&EndDate=30/06/2015

The code I'm using is:

```
        using (var eftTypesTask = connector.ForceClient.ExecuteRestApi<Transaction>("GetDirectDebitTransactions", "?StartDate=01/05/2015&EndDate=30/06/2015"))
        {                
            eftTypesTask.Wait();
            var eftJSON = eftTypesTask.Result;
        }
```

Any ideas/thoughts?